# Can you select more than one bulk email address?

Tags: civimail, contacts

Example 1: One contact, has personal and work email addresses, uses both to register for events, donate, etc. Depends on how they feel. They want bulk mail sent to both addresses. I would like to maintain one contact record instead of two.

Can you select more than one bulk mail address? I thought at one point you could but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Administer - CiviMail - CiviMail Component Settings
2. Enable multiple bulk email

[image]